# Connection adapter availability

Tags: ipod

How can I connect an older iPod touch second generation to a lightning dock?
The iPod has a 30 pin connector and the dock is a lightning connection.

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to [this](http://www.guuds.com/product/iP5-9020B__Lightning-8-Pin-Female-to-30-Pin-Male-Adapter-for-iPhone-4S-iPad-3-iPod-Touch-4-White.html) adapter on an Apple forum. It could be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but I didn't understand the question correct the first time.

Adapters from linghtning to 30-pins are not officially supported by apple.

When buying such an adapter could also result in stop working when you do not expect it.

---

For this problem Apple has introduced the

```
30-pins to lightning adapter

30-pins to lightning cable
```

These products have a chip inside that garuantees that the adapters keep working, even after software updates.

These products also support sending sound and video through the adapter/cable

These are the links to the products:

[30-pins to lightning adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter)

[30-pins to lightning cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD824ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter-02-m?fnode=3c)

Keep in mind that there are cheaper, non official adapters for this. The reason because they are cheaper is because they don't have a chip inside. It could be possible that those products stop working when you do not expect it, so use **at your own risk.**

---

Comment: You're answering a different question. This one is about the other way around.